# When Subscriber placed in record page Lightning Message Service (LMS) not receiving messages between different Apps

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-message-service, lightning-message-channel

I was trying to implement Lightning Message Service. But for some reason, the message is getting published but not reflected in the subscriber module. It is not throwing any errors not even in the console. I am pretty helpless to find out the issue. Any help is appreciated.

**publisher.html**

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="LMS Component A">
    <div class="slds-var-p-around_medium lgc-bg">
        <lightning-input type="text" label="Enter some text" onchange={handleInputChange}></lightning-input>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-var-p-around_medium lgc-bg">
    <lightning-button label="Publish" title="Non-primary action" 
    onclick={handleClick} class="slds-var-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
    </div>

</lightning-card>
```

**publisher.js**

```
import { LightningElement,wire } from 'lwc';
import SAMPLEMS from "@salesforce/messageChannel/FirstSampleMessage__c"
import { publish,MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';

export default class LmsComponentA extends LightningElement {
inputValue
@wire(MessageContext)
context

handleInputChange(event){
    this.inputValue=event.target.value;
    console.log('Text input :',this.inputValue)
}


handleClick(){
    console.log('Message published !!')
    let myMessage={
        lmsData:{
            textval:this.inputValue
        }
    }
    console.log('Msg :',myMessage)
    publish(this.context,SAMPLEMS,myMessage)
    console.log('Message published finished !!')
}
```

}

**subscriber.html**

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="LMS Component X">
    <div class="slds-var-p-around_medium lgc-bg">
        Message - {printMessage}
    </div>
</lightning-card>
<div class="slds-var-p-around_medium lgc-bg">
    <lightning-button label={buttonLabel} title="Click to Subscribe/Unsubscribe" 
    onclick={handlePubSubClick} class="slds-var-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
    </div>
</template>
```

**subscriber.js**

```
import { LightningElement,wire} from 'lwc'
import SAMPLEMS from '@salesforce/messageChannel/FirstSampleMessage__c'
import { subscribe,MessageContext, APPLICATION_SCOPE, unsubscribe } from 
'lightning/messageService'

//constsant declaration
const  SUBSCRIBE_LABEL='Subscribe'
const  UNSUBSCRIBE_LABEL='Unsubscribe'


export default class LmsComponentX extends LightningElement {
@wire (MessageContext)
context
subscription=null
_messggeBody;
_buttonLabel


connectedCallback(){
  this.buttonLabel=SUBSCRIBE_LABEL
}

  //************Pub/Sub button click logic***************
  handlePubSubClick(event){
      const labelText=event.target.label;
      this.handleSubscriptions(labelText);
  
    console.log('Code to be written')
}
//Logic to handle subscription and subscription
  handleSubscriptions(strOption){
    if(strOption===SUBSCRIBE_LABEL){
        console.log('handleSubscriptions called')
        this.subscription= subscribe(this.context,SAMPLEMS,(processinput)=> {this.handleMessage(processinput)},{scope:APPLICATION_SCOPE})
console.log('Subscribed')
this.buttonLabel=UNSUBSCRIBE_LABEL
        
    }
    else{
        unsubscribe(this.subscription)
        this.subscription=null
        this.buttonLabel=SUBSCRIBE_LABEL
 
    }
}


//received message processing
handleMessage(strMessage){
   // console.log('strMessage :', strMessage)
    this._messggeBody= strMessage.lmsData.textval;
   // console.log( this._messggeBody)
}



//getter methods
get printMessage(){
    return this._messggeBody;
}

get buttonLabel(){
    return  this._buttonLabel
}

//setter methods
set buttonLabel(btnText){
    this._buttonLabel=btnText;

}
```

}

**messageChannel**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningMessageChannel xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<masterLabel>FirstSampleMessage</masterLabel>
<isExposed>true</isExposed>
<description>This is a my first message channel.</description>
<lightningMessageFields>
    <fieldName>lmsData</fieldName>
    <description>This is the data passed</description>
</lightningMessageFields>
</LightningMessageChannel>
```

Comment: If I place both the component in a single app page, it is working properly. But if I place the subscriber component in a record page, it is not working. What am I missing here?

Comment: Both components must be in the same Lightning page, no matter if it's a record or an app page. If they are in different pages, LMS won't work.

Comment: Thanks, @RubenDG for your time. I also did find the same thing.  If I want to communicate from an app page to a record page, what is the most advisable option?